# Registering a custom URI protocol to handle custom resource loading from XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-4.0, uri

I'm working on a project where loose bits of XAML (and some associated IronPython code) will be dynamically loaded and executed by a client application. The client will be using a custom WCF service (and some local caching) to retrieve the XAML, backing scripts, and related resources (icons, images, etc..).

I would like to register a custom URI protocol/scheme to make it easier for the developers of the dynamic packages to reference their resources, like the following:

```xaml
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

                <ResourceDictionary Source="custom://MyPackage/Icons.xaml"  />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="custom://MyPackage/Styles.xaml" />
                <!--                        ^^^^^^                         -->

            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl>
```

As far as I can tell, I can derive a custom [UriParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uriparser.aspx) and [register it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uriparser.register.aspx), but that only seems to be half the battle. The remaining work is to provide whatever component is necessary to resolve the custom URI and retrieve the required content.

Is it possible to provide or override functionality in WPF to allow it to call my custom data service when one of my custom URIs is encountered? Or, if this is impossible, is there any sort of alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I understand, you need to create a class that derives from `WebRequest` and register it with [`WebRequest.RegisterPrefix`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.registerprefix.aspx).

Comment: I knew it had to be something easy. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, I wonder if you could create a new class that inherits from `ResourceDictionary` (since it is not `sealed`) and provide a `new` definition for `Source`. This would let you intercept the value being set to `Source` then and run it against your custom `UriParser`. This would also allow you to easily update the `ResourceDictionary` with the results.

Comment: It could work if Source was virtual because you could override it. But if you use `new`, it just hides the base class property and declares a new one. WPF will never use this property because it doesn't know about it

Comment: True - I was thinking that WPF would not need to use Source if the new definition has all the logic needed to update the ResourceDictionary with the new resources.